# What does pyplot size in points refer to?

Tags: python, matplotlib, size, point

What does pyplot size in points refer to? What is the unit? Size of 1 means: 1 pixel, 1 inch, 1 cm?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)

Comment: Matplotlib uses a ppi (points per inch) of 72, meaning one point is 1/72 inches.